# sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, oracle

- `echo $PATH` gives me below result :

> /home/mayank/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/bin

- `echo $ORACLE_HOME` fetches :

> /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client

- `echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gives (*set through `/etc/bash.bashrc` earlier, but now its showing as below*)

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH

doing `vim` for `.bash_profile` shows below things set :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #
Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    export PATH
```

Despite setting the `ld_library_path` in above file I'm still not getting the correct path in `env` despite running `sudo ldconfig` and then rebooting my machine!!

**what help I'm looking for :**

- set env vars correctly
- run sqlplus

Same question exists [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/716186/sqlplus-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libsqlplus-so-cannot-open-shared), but no solution is given there.

Comment: and there is the libsqlplus.so file located? try to find it with "sudo updatedb && locate libsqlplus.so" - then please tell us if you found it!

Comment: @WolfgangVogl : hi...thankx for ur response, on executing ur command i got this : `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/libsqlplus.so`

Comment: @WolfgangVogl : here is permission chekc result on so file => `ls -l /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/libsqlplus.so 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1303050 May 27  2013 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/libsqlplus.so`

Comment: Check out [this link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2015/09/installing-oracle-instant-database.html) for detailed steps with screenshot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As seen in the comments your Library is located at /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/, but your path just includes /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/bin...  you see why it can't find the library?

You can expand your LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/ directory (in your .profile or .environment or .bash_profile or (if you want it for all users) in the /etc/bash.bashrc file) - i don't know if sqlplus takes care of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH - just have a try.

To see to what LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set you have to type:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

(note the $ if you want to read the value!)

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi..i really appreciate you taking  out time for this, i updated `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/` and then ran `sqlplus` but still same error!! :(

Comment: there was a lib `libaio1` missing too...had too sudo upgrade after your solution...now solved...yeyeyeye!! :D

Answer (score 1):

There are some files under the `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/` directory which are not readable by other groups.

```
cd /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib/
chmod +r *
```

Then it works in my environment.